# Can concentration spells be "adjusted" while silenced?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components

For an example, the party is fighting Strahd, a vampire spellcaster.  The party cleric casts *Dawn*, off center on Strahd to only affect him. Then the party wizard casts *silence* directly on top of Strahd, which will also affect the cleric.  On Strahd's turn, he moves out of the effected area of *Dawn*.  When the cleric's turn comes back around, they will attempt to move *Dawn* to return Strahd into the spells effected area.

The Relevant parts of *Silence* (from *PHB p.276*):

> For the duration, no sound can be created within or pass through a 20-foot radius sphere centered on a
> point you choose within range. ... **Casting a spell that includes a verbal component is impossible there.**

This does make it clear that as long as the cleric remains inside the effected area of silence, they cannot cast any spells with verbal components, which shouldn't be a problem as they have already cast the spell, and are just concentrating on it.

The relevant parts of *Dawn* (from *XGtE p. 153-154*):

> Components: **V**, S, M (a sunburst pendant worth at least 100gp)
>
> If you're within 60 feet of the cylinder, you can move it up to 60 feet as a bonus action on your turn.

Moving the cylinder is not "casting a spell," however it is not specified whether or not this bonus action would require the same components as the initial casting of the spell.  If doing so does not require any verbal component, then that also would mean that the cleric does not need the other components. This means if an ally of Strahd took the sunburst pendant from the cleric this would not stop them from concentrating on the spell, or from being able to move the cylinder on their turn.

Given this situation, is it possible for the cleric to move the *Dawn* cylinder while remaining inside the silence area?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Spells specifically state when their actions require speaking

The [*dawn*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dawn) spell states:

> [...] If you're within 60 feet of the cylinder, you can move it up to 60 feet as a bonus action on your turn.

Compare this to spells like [*unseen servant*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/unseen-servant), [*finger of death*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death), and [*summon greater demon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-greater-demon) spells (emphasis mine):

> [...] Once on each of your turns as a bonus action, you can **mentally command** the servant to move up to 15 feet and interact with an object. [...]
>
> [...] A humanoid killed by this spell rises at the start of your next turn as a zombie that is permanently under your command, following your **verbal orders** to the best of its ability.
>
> [...] When you summon it and on each of your turns thereafter, you can issue a **verbal command** to it (requiring no action on your part), telling it what it must do on its next turn. [...]

Because the *dawn* spell does not state that you need to speak (mentally or verbally) to move its effect, you do not have to do so.

---

#### Spells specifically state when their components must remain on-hand

The *dawn* spell does not state that its material component (the Sunburst Pendant) must remain on your person, in your hand, or anything of the sort. Compare this to the [*warding bond*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/warding-bond) spell's material component (emphasis mine):

> [...] a pair of platinum rings worth at least 50 gp each, which you and the target **must wear for the duration** [...]

Because the *dawn* spell does not state that you need to keep the Sunburst Pendant in your hand (or even on your person), you do not have to do so.

Even if you are *silenced* and your Sunburst Pendant were obliterated, you could still move the cylinder formed by *dawn*.