# Can spiritual weapon continue to be used if caster is silenced?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

if a cleric is silenced after  casting spiritual weapon, can they continue  to use their bonus action to move and attack with the spiritual weapon.  Or does the cleric need to use verbal means to control the spiritual weapon after initially casting?

Comment: Does this answer your question: "[Can concentration spells be “adjusted” while silenced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169482)"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Medix2 There is the distinction that *spiritual weapon* does not require concentration, but I'm not sure whether that matters to querent or dupe status.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Reading through the other question, it doesn’t look like concentration mattered to that answer either.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Yeah that distinction is why I didn't mark it a duplicate. Whether or not concnetration makes a difference is not obvious

Comment: Oberon12, I've closed this question as a duplicate because I think it is the same as another question even though that uses *dawn* as an example of a spell with additional actions as part of its duration, and refers to these as concentration spells. If you think this is different enough to deserve it's own answer please tell us, clarify why and we'll see what need to be done (probably mostly editing that clarification into the q and reopening). Also note that we consider dupes to be a good thing, because this would help others find the other question.

Comment: @Medix2 And on reflection, the question doesn't really care about it being concentration either, it just uses that as a term to refer to spells with additional actions to be taken over their duration.

Comment: Yes. That helps.  I didn't notice that question when I searched.  Thank you